# Can not update the data of SQLite database in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I try to update my data in the SQLite database but when I do db.update the ide through an error and convince me to create a local var for it

```
public void updateEmployee(int sno, String name, double increment){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues v= new ContentValues();

        v.put("mytag sno", sno);
        v.put("mytag name", name);
        v.put("mytag increment", increment);

        db.update("myemployee","sno=?", new String[]{String.valueOf("sno"),new String[]{});
        db.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
db.update("myemployee",v, "sno=?",new String[]{String.valueOf("sno"));
```

As update statement works like this

```
database.update("Table name","Contentvalues",where clause, value of where clause);
```

Comment: It's shows the same error

Comment: Can you post the error

Comment: Right now the ide does not give an error but the method not working